# angularjs dialog form data not updating scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-material

I'm creating a small app where I open an angular material dialog to edit customer address information. Currently the dialog opens and displays the existing address information and when the data in the dialog is edited and submitted the database is updated. However, the address information on the page does not update itself.

The Add1 and Add2 on the page should update to the new information after the database has been updated. I can't figure out how to do this please help?

I don't want the main page to update as the user is typing the address, only when the exec function has completed.

HTML:

```
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class="md-padding dialogdemoBasicUsage" id="popupContainer" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">


          <div class="dialog-demo-content" layout="row" ayout="row" layout-wrap="" layout-margin="" layout-align="center">
            <p>Add1: {{ customerdetails.Add1 }}</p>
            <p>Add2: {{ customerdetails.Add2 }}</p>
            <br/>
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showTabDialog($event)">
              Open Dialog
            </md-button>
          </div>


          <script type="text/ng-template" id="tabDialog.tmpl.html"><md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
          <form>
            <md-toolbar>
              <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

                <span flex></span>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
                  <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
              </div>
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-dialog-content style="max-width:800px;max-height:810px; ">
              <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
                <md-tab label="one">
                  <md-content class="md-padding">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block">
                     <label>Address 1</label>
                      <input ng-model="customerdetails.Add1">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block">
                       <label>Address 2</label>
                       <input ng-model="customerdetails.Add2">
                    </md-input-container>
                  </md-content>
                </md-tab>

              </md-tabs>
            </md-dialog-content>

            <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
              <md-button ng-click="editAddressSubmit()" style="margin-right:20px;" >
                Update
              </md-button>
            </md-dialog-actions>
          </form>
        </md-dialog>
        </script>
        </div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])

        .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia) {
          $scope.customerdetails={
            Add1: 'line 1',
            Add2: 'line 2'
          }

          $scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
            $mdDialog.show({
              controller: 'AppCtrl',
              templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
              parent: angular.element(document.body),
              targetEvent: ev,
              clickOutsideToClose:true
            })

          };

          $scope.cancel = function() {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
          };

          $scope.editAddressSubmit = function() {
             console.log('edit address submit funtion clicked')
             //in live code the database is updated here but the Add1 and Add2 is not updated on the main page once the dialog is closed!
             return $scope.exec('call/UpdateCustomerSQL',
                 {
                   Add1: $scope.customerdetails.Add1,
                   Add2: $scope.customerdetails.Add2
               }
             ).then(function() { // close popup
                 console.log('then function close popup')
                 $mdDialog.cancel();
              })
             }
        }) //close controller
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that you will have to pass in an isolated `scope` so that your dialog's scope will not get binded to your parent scope. For this, you will have to use the parameters `local`, and use a different controller to handle the logic.

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: 'DialogCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
   parent: angular.element(document.body),
   targetEvent: ev,
   clickOutsideToClose: true,
   locals: {
     address1: $scope.customerdetails.Add1,
     address2: $scope.customerdetails.Add2,
   }
})
```

And then, you will use another controller `DialogCtrl` to handle whatever logic that is needed in the dialog. Here, you can inject in `address1` and `address2` into your controller, something along this line.

```
.controller('DialogCtrl',function($scope,$mdDialog, address1, address2){
   console.log(address1, address2) //this will have the values as $scope.customerdetails.Add1 and 2
}
```

Now you have successfully passed the data from your `AppCtrl` to your `DialogCtrl`, you can then perform your DB transcations. After that, you will have to resolve the promises so that your AppCtrl can get the updated data.

I forked your pen: http://codepen.io/cozyazure/pen/PzYzQd

I did not have your service, so I mocked a `$timeout` to mimick a promise return

Comment: thanks, this is good! Can I pass the whole customerdetails object in locals? As there are actually loads of variables, not just 2. thanks

Comment: @Janey let me know the outcome, and mark accepted answer if it has solved your problem (or at least point to the correct direction)